# how lucene count how many time the token is indexed?

Tags: java, lucene

I am using code from lucene in action from the 1st publication and lucene version 1.4.3. I use simple analyzer to analyze data which is "book book book" in a txt file. However when I use lukeall to browse the data, the rank column show that "book" only occur for once while I expect it to be 3.

[image: lukeall image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What gave you the impression that Luke's "Rank" column would display the number of occurances of the term like that?  I believe in 0.9, Rank displays the `docfreq`, that is, the number of documents in which the term appears (in later version, "Rank" is sequential, and "Freq" provides that statistic).  Adding some more data to your index would likely clarify what those statistics are meant to indicate.

Comment: Any idea how to know the number of occurrences of term in a single documents?

Comment: Browse to the document in the Documents tab, and then use the "Browse by Term" area to find the term you are interested in, which should provide the a "term freq in this doc".